# Aurelia: SystemJS error after updating jspm for validation

Tags: javascript, validation, jspm, aurelia

Till now I was using

```
"aurelia-validatejs": "npm:aurelia-validatejs@^0.6.0",
"aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@^0.10.0"
```

for validating properties of my application.

Today I tried to update the package for aurelia validation but after updating the package.json to

```
"aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1"
```

Whenever I am loading the application I getting the below error:

[image]

I am unable to resolve this issue, any help will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: I can't really reproduce this using a brand new skeleton-navigation app with SystemJS / JSPM. Could you provide more details? How are you configuring / importing bits of aurelia-validation into the app?